# When I use Mac(M2 silicon) to trans .html to .pdf by Chrome(command line tool), arising font error

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, html-to-pdf

2023-10-28 14:40:01.629 Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)[15564:3071066] CoreText note: Client requested name ".PingFangSC-Medium", it will get TimesNewRomanPSMT rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[NSFont systemFontOfSize:].
2023-10-28 14:40:01.629 Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)[15564:3071066] CoreText note: Set a breakpoint on CTFontLogSystemFontNameRequest to debug.
2023-10-28 14:40:01.632 Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)[15564:3071066] CoreText note: Client requested name ".PingFangSC-Medium", it will get TimesNewRomanPSMT rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[NSFont systemFontOfSize:].
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnKZM.png)

How to solve this font error? It is best to solve by just adding some new args.